# Using cross-validation to select the optimal polynomial degree in R

Tags: r

To begin with, I'm using R with the MASS library and the Boston data and relating the dis to nox variables.

What I'm trying to do is use cross-validation, cv, to select the optimal polynomial degree (between 1-10) and fit the optimal polynomial to the data and plot.
To do this I'm using a span that decreases from left to right and using cv to choose the best span.
Here's how I'm doing it:

```
library(MASS)
x<- Boston$nox
y<- Boston$dis

k <- 5
fold <- sample(k, nrow(Boston), replace=T)

## For each span from 1 to 10 we can calculate the CV test error:
mse <- vector(length=k)
span <- seq(1,10, by=1)
cv <- vector(length=length(span))

for (j in 1:length(span))
{
  for (i in 1:k)
  {
    foldi <- Boston[fold==i,]
    foldOther <- Boston[fold!=i,]
    f <- loess(y ~ x, data=foldOther, span=span[j])
    pred <- predict(f, foldi)
    mse[i] <-mean((pred - foldi$y)^2, na.rm=T) 
  }
  cv[j]<- mean(mse)
}

plot(span, cv)
```

The problem is, when I run the code i get 50 or more warnings! Here's the first 3:

```
1: 'newdata' had 89 rows but variables found have 506 rows
2: 'newdata' had 115 rows but variables found have 506 rows
3: 'newdata' had 106 rows but variables found have 506 rows
```

When I run the `plot(span,cv)` command i get the following warnings:

```
Error in plot.window(...) : need finite 'ylim' values
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In min(x) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
2: In max(x) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
```

Any suggestions as to what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're pulling out `dis` and `nox` into `y` and `x`, then subsetting `Boston`, **not** `x` and `y`. As your formula contains `x` and `y`, but you told it to fit with `foldOther`, which contains `nox` and `dis`, R goes hunting in the global workspace for `x` and `y`. It finds them, but they are of the full original length. Then `predict()` goes looking for `x` and `y`, doesn't find them in `foldi` but it does find them in the global workspace, but now `foldi` has fewer rows than the `x` and `y` it found, hence the first warning.

The second issue is that you evaluate the MSE using `foldi$y`, which *doesn't exist* - there is no `y` in `Boston`.

You'll make life a lot easier for yourself if you ignore creating new `x` and `y` as that just confuses things. Instead refer directly to the response and predictor variables as they are known in `Boston`. For example:

```
library(MASS)

k <- 5
fold <- sample(k, nrow(Boston), replace = TRUE)

## For each span from 1 to 10 we can calculate the CV test error:
mse <- numeric(k)
span <- seq(1, 10, by = 1)
cv <- numeric(length(span)))

for (j in seq_along(span))
{
  for (i in seq_len(k))
  {
    take <- fold == i
    foldi <- Boston[take, ]
    foldOther <- Boston[!take, ]
    f <- loess(dis ~ nox, data=foldOther, span=span[j])
    pred <- predict(f, foldi)
    mse[i] <- mean((pred - foldi$dis)^2, na.rm = TRUE)
  }
  cv[j]<- mean(mse)
}

plot(span, cv)
```

producing:

[image]